# Install os using external drive in internal drive

Tags: software-installation, hard-drive

does installing os from external drive install it on internal hdd.
I don't know much about this area pls help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: It's completely up to you.  I've installed an OS from an internal drive to another part of the internal drive, from external drive/media to internal, from external to external & other combinations. The major limits are the machine firmware itself (ie. what will it boot) & other details you've not provided..  To boot the OS post-install; your machine has to be capable of booting the device you install to (I've had some that can only boot when a single external disk drive is connected; other later firmware had that issue fixed)